# C++ WTL8.1 How to create a window in a new thread with message loop?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, wtl

I saw this asked a lot of ways but never saw an actual working code snip.

I tried this no doubt naive attempt to create a new thread with a new window and message loop. I have a function that must open a window & process its messages, and must run in environments where it may be called from application with no existing message loop (and no other windows) or the usual mfc message loop or a WTL message loop. I saw some stuff about AddMessageLoop and Modules? but it appeared that was for the main application. In any case, there may or may not be a WTL module out there. Need a stand alone window with a basic message loop. Passing in a WTL class with window not yet opened, so Window opens in same thread as loop. Does class object also have to be created in the new thread?

```
// does not work.... 
static DWORD WINAPI MyRunThread(__in LPVOID lpParameter)
{
CMessageLoop theLoop;
WTLsubclass *nav = (WTLsubclass *) lpParameter;

nav->CreateWindow(); 
int nRet = theLoop.Run();

return nRet;
}

CreateThread(0,0,MyRunThread,&nav,0,0);
```

Comment: If it may be called from an app with no windows, you will probably be unable to create it with a Window class parameter.

Comment: So this code snippet of yours, does it work? Looks good for me - you start a thread, you create window there and you keep pumping messages.

Answer (score 0):

See comments for alterations needed.
Gotcha #1 was & operator does not work on WTL classes
Gotcha #2, is never name your events. If you link with unknown other objects,
its likely someone already used the same name, and Windows decides that the same names means the same event, even though multiple CreateEvent() calls are use. No Name, 
no "aliasing" of supposedly different events.

Non-Gotcha, if you DON'T want the "main" message handler handling your messages, you don't need _Module or to "tell" anything about your message loop. If you want independent
window with independent loop, see below.

===================================================

```
static DWORD WINAPI MyRunThread(__in LPVOID lpParameter)
{
CMessageLoop theLoop;
WTLsubclass *nav = (WTLsubclass *) lpParameter;

nav->CreateWindow(); 
SetEvent(WindowCreatedEvent) // signal event HANDLE type for worker thread

int nRet = theLoop.Run();

return nRet;
}

//CreateThread(0,0,MyRunThread,&nav,0,0); // & wont work on WTL class objects
// some genius overloaded the & operator on WTL class objects, just because in C++ you can

//Workaround to get address of WTL class object
CLASSnav nav[1];
CLASSnav *pnav = nav; // because arrays is address of first element.
CreateThread(0,0,MyRunThread,pnav,0,0);
```

Comment: Actually there's nothing wrong with naming events as long as you include a GUID to make the name unique.

Answer (score 0):

`SetWindowLongPtr` and `GetWindowLongPtr`, use these to get to your instance from within the window proc, and then set a condition variable on `WM_ACTIVATE`.

In your client code:

```
// Create window, this setups the window and runs a message loop, its guts are ran in a different thread
createwindow();
// Wait to be shown, this presumes the existence of a mutext (m) and a condition_variable (cv) in your instance
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
cv.wait_for(lock, std::chrono::milliseconds(800));
```

During window setup and creation, this can be in your thread proc:

```
// Create window (RegisterClass, CreateWindow, etc)
...
SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, /*your instance*/ ...);   
ShowWindow(hwnd, ...);
...
// Pump
```

In your window proc:

```
...
switch(msg)
{
    case WM_ACTIVATE:
    {
        your_instance* inst = (your_instance*)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA);
        inst->cv->notify_one();
    }
    break;
...
```